# Gelu activation in Python

Tags: python

Hi I'm trying to using a gelu activation in a neural net. I'm having trouble calling it in my layer.

I'm thinking its tf.erf that is messing it up but I'm not well versed in tensorflow

```
def gelu(x):

 cdf = 0.5 * (1.0 + tf.erf(x / tf.sqrt(2.0)))
 return x * K.cdf

get_custom_objects().update({'gelu': Activation(gelu)})

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim = len(x[0,:]), activation = 'relu')) 
model.add(Dense(4, activation =  'gelu' ))
```

Comment: what is the error

Comment: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'erf'

Comment: try tf.math.erf

Comment: Okay, thank you I think it worked. I don't have to backend too correct?